# How to get length of text for last line in UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

In my app, I'm trying to have the UILable time text aligned in a way like WhatsApp where if the last sentence of a UITextView's message text is too long the time would be pushed to the next line. So I'm actually trying to align the UILabel's time according to the UITextView's message box.

[message box time layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MIjW.jpg)

```
This is a text message.  7:16PM


This is a longer
text message.    7:15PM


This is an even longer
text message till end.
                7.15PM
```

One way I could think of was to use UITextView's class and grab the length of the last line and calculate the text width as compared with the UITextView's width to know if it exceeds but no luck. Is there any way?

Comment: Is your time text appended with your message text? If yes then you don't have to do like this. You have to use 2 controls here one for message and another for time.

Comment: Hi, no it's using 2 separate components and not appended together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I wrote which solved my issue. Thanks to Greg for pointing me in the right direction.

```
+ (BOOL)didTextMoveToNewline:(NSString *)text previousSize:(CGSize)previousSize {
    UIFont *messageBubbleFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    float maximumTextWidth = 188;

    NSString *finalText = [[NSString alloc] init];
    finalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 10:00PM ", text];
    CGRect stringRect = [finalText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maximumTextWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                        attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : messageBubbleFont }
                                           context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = CGRectIntegral(stringRect).size;

    if (stringSize.height > previousSize.height)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hack would be to automatically add a blank space the length of the time to the end of every message.

```
let userMessageLabel.text = userMessage + "        "
```

Then let the time always overlap the last line. If the amount of spaces is correct, the text and time will never touch.

Comment: hi this won't work as the UITextView and UILabel are separate components and aligned using constraints.

Comment: actually you pointed me in the right direction of the hack. What I need to do is add the space at the end and using boundingRectWithSize to compare the height before and after the append. thanks!